# CSS Transform reset - which is the correct approach ..?

Tags: html, css, transform

** all hover code is working . i m confuse which one is correct syntax for reseting transform . i did not find any blog article thats give me full detaiils of css transform how it computed behind the scene**

```
<style>
 .box{
   height: 100px;
   width : 100px;
   background-color:red;
   transition: transform 0.5s ease;
   transform: translateX(10px) scale(2) rotate(45deg);
}
.box:hover{
  transform: none ;
}

or

.box:hover{
   transform: translateX(0) scale(0) rotate(0);
}

or

.box:hover{
   transform: translateX(0);
}
</style>

<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: All of them look fine to me, as long as they work. The third one only removes the `translateX`-property though? You wanted to reset the transform completely, right?

Comment: the third one transform is computed in matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

Comment: is transform: none is equal to matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) ?

Comment: when i use transform: none its lost containing block but when i use transform: translateX(0) its become containing block and eqaul to matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)

Answer (score 3):

As per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/transform), the [Initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/initial_value) is none.

**You can reset the transformation using:**

```
div.someclass {
    transform: none;
}
```

**Using vendor prefix:**

```
div.someclass {
    -webkit-transform: none; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-transform: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-transform: none; /* IE 9 */
         -o-transform: none; /* Opera */
            transform: none;
}
```

The `transform CSS property` lets you *rotate, scale, skew or translate* an element. It modifies the coordinate space of the CSS visual formatting model.

If the property has a value different than none, a stacking context will be created. In that case, the element will act as a containing block for any position: fixed; or position: absolute; elements that it contains.

**Syntax**

```
/* Keyword values */
transform: none;

/* Function values */
transform: matrix(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0);
transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
transform: perspective(17px);
transform: rotate(0.5turn);
transform: rotate3d(1, 2.0, 3.0, 10deg);
transform: rotateX(10deg);
transform: rotateY(10deg);
transform: rotateZ(10deg);
transform: translate(12px, 50%);
transform: translate3d(12px, 50%, 3em);
transform: translateX(2em);
transform: translateY(3in);
transform: translateZ(2px);
transform: scale(2, 0.5);
transform: scale3d(2.5, 1.2, 0.3);
transform: scaleX(2);
transform: scaleY(0.5);
transform: scaleZ(0.3);
transform: skew(30deg, 20deg);
transform: skewX(30deg);
transform: skewY(1.07rad);

/* Multiple function values */
transform: translateX(10px) rotate(10deg) translateY(5px);
transform: perspective(500px) translate(10px, 0, 20px) rotateY(3deg);

/* Global values */
transform: inherit;
transform: initial;
transform: revert;
transform: revert-layer;
transform: unset;
```

The transform property may be specified as either the keyword value `none` or as one or more `<transform-function>` values.

You can watch this article for more details: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Comment: which one is correct way for reseting transform ?

Comment: @codenewbie I edited my answer just look again and I am sure you will get your answer.

Comment: is transform: none equal to matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
 ?

Comment: Yes, you can say it. But you have to understand the logic of the matrix. 
transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); is Identical to transform: scale(1,1);

Comment: matrix(a, b, c, d, e, f) does everything that the previously listed transformation does.

The two arguments, a and d are for scaling the element in the X-direction and the Y-direction, respectively. Identically to that of the scale(a, d) method.

The second and third arguments b and c are for skewing the element. The two values work identically to that of the skew(b, c) method.

Finally, the last two arguments e and f are for translating the element in the X-direction and the Y-direction, respectively. Identically to that of the translate(e, f) method.

Comment: which approach is good and why ? .box:hover{
  transform: none ;
}

or

.box:hover{
   transform: translateX(0) scale(0) rotate(0);
}

or

.box:hover{
   transform: translateX(0);
}

Comment: Actually, the point is what you what to do??

Answer (score 1):

the class is **box1** and you write **box:hover** it should be **box1:hover**.

```
<style>
 .box1{
   height: 100px;
   width : 100px;
   background-color:red;
   transform: translateX(10px) scale(2) rotate(45deg);
}
.box1:hover{
  transform: none ;
}
</style>
```

Comment: i have updated it, but my question is that what is a correct way for reseting transfrom ?